# migrating from one-to-many to many-to-many: interm. table does not have UNIQUE constraint

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-migrations

**TL;DR;** changing completely different field in the same migration as introducing many-to-many field leads intermediate table does not have `UNIQUE` constraint.

**Root challenge.**

I need to replace one-to-many relation with many-to-many.

**Step-by-step.**

Assume initially I have:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    pass


class Test2(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    test = models.ForeignKey(Test)
```

After changing test2.test into `ManyToMany`

```
class Test(models.Model):
    pass


class Test2(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
```

and running `makemigrations`/`migrate` I'm getting new table `test2_test` with UNIQUE constraint for pair `test_id` + `test2_id` and that's definitely I expect.

But once I wanted to update another field also:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    pass


class Test2(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    tests = models.ManyToManyField(Test)
```

And `test2_test` does not get `UNIQUE INDEX` for `test_id` + `test2_id`.

As a workaround I've finally moved changes for different field into separated migration.

**Question**

Does anybody know reason for a such behavior?

Comment: I'm using SQLite. But believe it does not related to specific RDBMS.

Comment: Why would you get a unique index? ManyToMany by definition means that the relationship is not unique - there  can be any number of `Test2` objects related to `Test` objects.

Comment: I'm actually getting it. but once there are additional changes - then I don't.

Comment: actually there is no much sense NOT having unique index there. while there are no additional fields on intermediate model we could not differ relations to the same object. say, we have `Family` and `Human` with many-to-many relation. if the same person was linked to the same family twice what would it mean and how could we handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it has been [reported to django team](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28846) It's known bug and it has already been fixed for upcoming v.2 release.

Until then workaround should be used with introducing ManyToMany field separately from any other model's changes.